# What data structure should I use for object storage, for easily generating primary keys for new entries?

Tags: java

I'm doing a school project in Java and I the following question have arisen:

I have an entity with attributes - id, name, phone.. with id as the unique primary key. I want to store them in a data structure(such as list..). Then in the application I obtain the data for creating a new instance (name, phone..) and I want to create a new instance of the entity and store it in my data structure with a new unique id. The id shouldn't be random, it would be best if the id rised continuously with the size of the list. Also I dont want to reuse ids.

The first implementation that comes to my mind is to use ArrayList and simply set id as indexes. But `ArrayList.remove(int index)` after removal shifts all following elements to left. I assume that `ArrayList.remove(Object o)` works the same, but i would be gratefull i I'm proven wrong. Determining ids from last element would not work either. I could go through all of them but that seems inefiicient.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I'm assuming you're not storing the entity in a persistent storage like a database system.

Comment: No, not yet. Now it is in memory only. But it will be next week :) We are doing a project during whole semester and every week we add new functionality. We started with UML, then testing and next week its JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep a counter for them. You could use a static value in the class (you may need to synchronize it for multi-threaded classes.)

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
class MyClass {


    // thread safe
    private static final AtomicInteger safeCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    private final int uniqueId; // can never change uniqueId
    private String name; // the data of the class

    public MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.uniqueId = MyClass.safeCounter.getAndIncrement();
    } 

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof MyClass) { // instanceof also does null check :-)
            MyClass mc = (MyClass)o;
            return mc.uniqueId == this.uniqueId;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return uniqueId;
    }
}
```

If this is for homework, or if threadsafety isn't a concern, you can use a simple static int

```
class MyClass {

    private static int nextUniqueId() {
        int result = counter;
        counter++;
        return result;
    }

    // not thread safe
    private static int counter;

    private final int uniqueId; // can never change uniqueId
    private String name; // the data of the class

    public MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.uniqueId = nextUniqueId();
    } 

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof MyClass) { // instanceof also does null check :-)
            MyClass mc = (MyClass)o;
            return mc.uniqueId == this.uniqueId;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return uniqueId;
    }
}
```

Comment: can the state of the AtomicCounter be stored? I mean - can I store It into a file or database and then read it back and continue where I stopped?

Comment: Absolutely! You can use `safeCounter.get()` and print that out to the database or file (any changes you make after that won't be recorded, obviously!) You can load it with `safeCounter.set(int)` which you could simply wrap in a static method.

Comment: This is a fine answer that glowcoder provided, especially for a school project.  But to be absolutely clear, in projects that are production quality, if you will be storing objects in the database, it is far superior to get your identifiers directly from the database.

Comment: @hooknc I'll go along on that. I wouldn't consider it 'far' superior, because there's places where it's undesirable. (for example if you create throwaway objects that will never be put into the database, you wouldn't want to constantly be pinging the database for the next id.) For the most part, though, yes it's a very sound practice for production code. (+1) It's especially important (actually, *required*) for distributed systems. You wouldn't want multiple systems keeping track of their own "nextId"

Comment: Personally, I've struggled mightily with what to do with 'throw away' objects (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717018/spring-formbackingobject-business-object-creation-and-factories).  I believe at this point a 'throw away' object should be a different type of object and there should be a translation strategy that will transform the 'throw away' into the full fledged object if needed.  Therefore, avoiding requests to the database until absolutely required.  +1 on using the db for distributed systems, this was my thinking exactly, and in the case of many disparate systems using the same db.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Factory that users a Strategy for generating your identifiers?

*Edited to answer question about factories*

A Factory is a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) that is used to encapsulate the creation of different types of Objects.  A Strategy is another design pattern that is used to encapsulate the behavior of specific business logic that might have different rules or that might change over time.

In your case you clearly require a new Identifier for each object that needs to be unique.  You also stated in your question comments above that eventually you will be storing your objects in a database, which also would most likely require you to get your identifier from your database in the long run.

Here is a smallish example of using a Factory to create your User Objects instead of just using new().  Please kindly disregard any spelling or compile mistakes, I wrote the following code with out the assistance of a compiler or IDE.

```
public interface UserFactory {
    User createUser();
}

public interface IdentifierStrategy {
    // I just picked Long for ease of use.
    Long getIdentifier();
}

public class UserFactoryImpl {
    private final IdentifierStrategy identifierStrategy;
    public UserFactoryImpl(final IdentifierStrategy identifierStrategy) {
        this.identifierStrategy = identifierStrategy;
    }
    public User createUser() {
        Long identifier = this.identifierStrategy.getIdentifier();
        User user = new User(identifier);
        return user;
    }
}

public class LongIdentifierStrategy implements IdentifierStrategy {
    public Long getIdentifier() {
        // Do something here that will return a unique long.
        Long long = new Long(1);
        return long;
    }
}

// In the long term, you would most likely use this IdentiferStrategy
// to get your identifiers from the database.
public class JDBCIdentifierStrategy implements IdentifierStrategy {
    public Long getIdentifer() {
        // Get a jdbc connection from a jdbc connection pool.
        // Get the next identifier from the databsae.
        Long long = new Long(1);
        return long;
    }
}
```

Now, in the long run, if your requirement change for how you need to identifier your User objects, you would only need to write a new IdentifierStrategy and update your UserFactoryImpl with that new Strategy.

Comment: sorry I don't understand that :) could you please describe it a little?

Comment: Updated my answer to give a clearer explanation of what I was recommending with factories and strategies.

Answer (score 0):

One important question: what's the scope of the uniqueness?

Just for the duration of a run of the application? Do you have a single thread or multiple threads, so unique across those threads? Or could there be several copies of the app running at the same time, so unique across all instances, even across many machines? Will you save the data somewhere and so need uniqueness across future runs of the program too?

Two fundamental schemes:

a). use a database, they usually offer some kind of auto-generated primary key: you insert the record, it gives you a unique key.

b). generate the key yourself, in this case: first isolate the key generation to it's own class, then you can make the generation as clever as you wish. Sketch:

```
some initialisation, generate an initial value, simple case it's zero, or it derives from the current date/time, or MAC address of your machine, or whatever

provide a getNextId() function, which probably needs to  be synchronized if threads are involved.
```

A very simple scheme, which will be OK for low volume systems, just use

```
new Date().getTime();
```

You can also look for GUID generators, which produce something unique, but rather bigger than an int.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to have an Object Pooling for ID generation. When the entity is "deleted", the ID should be returned to the pool, and when needing a new ID, the pool should either

1. Give you a new ID (if old ID doesn't exists in pool) or
2. Create a new ID for an entity.

The problem is that you will have to create an entity management system that caters for returning the "used" ID to the pool if entity is "deleted" (bear in mind the multithreading environment, which you will need to manage).

Alternatively, use a database system which provides primary key generation (most uses `AUTO_INCREMENT`).