# initialize a nested object inside command bean, Simpleformcontroller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a class Account

```
public class Account {
private int id;
private String name;
//getters and setters
}
```

and a class Contact

```
private class Contact {
private int contactid;
private Account account;
//getters and setters
}
```

In a simple form controller, we initialize the command object through setCommandName method. Now my question is how should i initialize the account object that is related to this contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you initialize your command object in the formBackingObject() method, which typically involves actually calling `new Contact()` or else using some type of factory object.

To initialize the nested objects, you pretty much have to do it by hand.  Options include:

within your formBackingObject method:

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.setAccount(new Account());
```

or, within the Contact object itself:

```
private Account account = new Account();
```

For more discussion, including a description of the rather more involved way that I ended up dealing with this, see my question [Best Practice for Spring MVC form-backing object tree initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378066/best-practice-for-spring-mvc-form-backing-object-tree-initialization)

Comment: Instead of initializing it using the 'new', cant we do it through bean injection? what i am trying to say is, i have a contactController bean with the following definition

Comment: <bean id="contactController" class="com.advanstar.datatrax.web.action.ContactController">
        <property name="commandName">
            <value>contact</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandClass">
            <value>com.advanstar.datatrax.model.Contact</value>
        </property>
    which initializes the command class, now can't i say <bean id="contactBean" class="com.advanstar.datatrax.model.Contact">
 <property name="account" ref="accountBean"/>
</bean>

Comment: to inject the account object into the contact object?

Comment: Specifying the commandClass property doesn't refer to configured beans, it just tells the controller what class the command object is (behind the scenes it just calls `BeanUtils.instantiateClass()` on that class).  And you wouldn't want to simply inject a new Contact object anyway; a lot of the time you want to initialize the command bean yourself based on data in the request or in the session (e.g. someone wants to edit a Contact that already exists).  That's what `formBackingObject()` is for.

Comment: If you think your question is answered, you can click the checkbox to the left of the answer to indicate that you accept that answer.